# Sorting Node's on the base of parent-Id

Tags: javascript, function, sorting, recursion

Want to sort my data all node come first before calling its parent node

```
[
  {
    "id": 7832454551,
    "name": "usr",
    "type": "DIRECTORY"
  },
  {
    "id": 7832454554,
    "name": "applications",
    "type": "DIRECTORY",
    "parentId": 7832454553
  },
  {
    "id": 7832454555,
    "name": "mimeinfo.cache",
    "type": "FILE",
    "parentId": 7832454554
  },
  {
    "id": 7832454553,
    "name": "share",
    "type": "DIRECTORY",
    "parentId": 7832454552
  },
  {
    "id": 7832454552,
    "name": "local",
    "type": "DIRECTORY",
    "parentId": 7832454551
  }
]
```

want to update data like this using javascript

```
[
  {
    "id": 7832454551,
    "name": "usr",
    "type": "DIRECTORY"
  },
  {
    "id": 7832454552,
    "name": "local",
    "type": "DIRECTORY",
    "parentId": 7832454551
  },
  {
    "id": 7832454553,
    "name": "share",
    "type": "DIRECTORY",
    "parentId": 7832454552
  },
  {
    "id": 7832454554,
    "name": "applications",
    "type": "DIRECTORY",
    "parentId": 7832454553
  },
  {
    "id": 7832454555,
    "name": "mimeinfo.cache",
    "type": "FILE",
    "parentId": 7832454554
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi Hajaj, Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you show us your efforts What code you tried to solve this issue? What challenge or error you faced when you tried to solve?

Comment: Thanks, want to make a folder structure using there type and name

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: there is a parent id that's contain another node id. when we pick data one by one if parent-id node not exist  then found error. i just want to sort my data before starting making nods.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
const sortedData = [
  {
    "id": 7832454551,
    "name": "usr",
    "type": "DIRECTORY"
  },
  {
    "id": 7832454554,
    "name": "applications",
    "type": "DIRECTORY",
    "parentId": 7832454553
  },
  {
    "id": 7832454555,
    "name": "mimeinfo.cache",
    "type": "FILE",
    "parentId": 7832454554
  },
  {
    "id": 7832454553,
    "name": "share",
    "type": "DIRECTORY",
    "parentId": 7832454552
  },
  {
    "id": 7832454552,
    "name": "local",
    "type": "DIRECTORY",
    "parentId": 7832454551
  }
].sort(function(a,b){

if(a.parentId!= undefined && b.parentId != undefined){
  return a.parentId > b.parentId
}
return false;


});

console.log(sortedData);
```

Comment: no its working ur code make  data like this [ { id: 7832454551, name: 'usr', type: 'DIRECTORY' },
  { id: 7832454554,
    name: 'applications',
    type: 'DIRECTORY',
    parentId: 7832454553 },
  { id: 7832454555,
    name: 'mimeinfo.cache',
    type: 'FILE',
    parentId: 7832454554 },
  { id: 7832454553,
    name: 'share',
    type: 'DIRECTORY',
    parentId: 7832454552 },
  { id: 7832454552,
    name: 'local',
    type: 'DIRECTORY',
    parentId: 7832454551 } ]

Comment: need to be all data in sequence

Comment: it's working. it is not sorting the original data arrray,  it returns the sorted output

Comment: u can see we need "7832454553" node on second number